# How to display messages at MDI form level in VB6

Tags: vb6, mdi

Friends, I've a VB6 application. I'm using 1 MDI form and multiple child forms. Now what I require is, I want to show some messages depending on the child forms(like-If there is no data in the database,then message will be "Enter master data first", messages regarding mandatory fields etc. etc.). I'm already using 1 status bar at lower end to display some other information. I don't want the display to be on the forms(child forms). I want it at MDI level. Is it possible to do(As far I know, MDI form doesn't support keeping any control on it)? If yes then which VB6 control I should use?
I'm asking this question after trying many options. Without knowing, why do you downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As far I know, MDI form doesn't support keeping any control on it**

This is not entirely accurate.  There are some controls you can put on an MDI form.  In this case, you should add a picture box control, and then put another control within the picture box control.  I have done this in my own application and it works well.

Comment: @G Mastros Aha,is it possible to add picture box on an MDI form?Then I think it'll solve my problem.Let me check.Thans anyway..

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to create a event that handles messages in your application. The child forms would simply raise the event, then the MDI form would handle the event raised, and then the message would be displayed in whatever manner you choose. If you need more information on raising events and listening for them, here is a [link](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/1430631/Declaring-and-Raising-Events-in-Visual-Basic-6.htm) that Google found for me.

Comment: I wanted to show messages in MDI level.I don't have any issue regarding raising the event, that is handled.